# norm of orthogonal set

Tags: inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, gram-schmidt

Say $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space and $B = \{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ a basis for $V.$
Suppose that we apply the Gram-Schmidt process to this basis in order to obtain the orthogonal
basis $\{w_1,\dots, w_n\}.$ Show that
$$\|v_1\|^2 +\dots+ \|v_n\|^2 \geq \|w_1\|^2 + . . . + \|w_n\|^2$$

Hello guys. I am trying to prove this. Now i am trying to do induction. Showed for $n$ is $1$ and supposed up to $n-1.$ Also i writed $w_1$ up to $w_n$ applying Gram Schmidt. But at the final step which is showing $\|v_n\|^2\geq\|w_n\|^2,$ i could not find a way to show it. Can you help?

Comment: Can't you express $v_{1}$ up to $v_{n}$ in terms of $w_{1}$ up to $w_{n}$? The entire Gram-Schmidt process can be described as a matrix decomposition $$V=QR$$ where $V$ contains the original basis vectors and $Q$ contains the output orthonormal basis vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})=\operatorname{span}(w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1})$. Then $w_n=v_n+u$ with $u\in U$ and $w_n\perp U$. In particular, $w_n\perp u$. Then
$$ \|v_n\|^2=v_n\cdot v_n=(w_n-u)\cdot (w_n- u)=w_n\cdot w_n-2(w_n\cdot u)+u\cdot u=\|w_n\|^2+\|u\|^2\ge \|w_n\|^2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much now i got it. What about equality? When it happens? I think it seems that is first basis is also orthogonal then equality happens. But i do not know how to prove it.